# Work done by gravitational force

Tags: calculus, physics, contour-integration, solution-verification

In my calculus class we learned about line integrals, and for homework we have exercise to find work done by gravitational force on material dot with mass $m$ which follows path of the elipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ in second quadrant in positive direction (clockwise).

If I understood physics part of problem, gravitational force field is $f(X)=(0,0,-mg)$ and it's conservative which means work only depends on change in $z$ coordinate. And using formula with dot product I got:
$W=\int_C-mgdz$ and since parametrization of curve $C$ is $x=a \cos t, z=c \sin t, t\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ I have $W=-mgc$. It makes sense to me, but I'm not sure weather my conclusions are right. Can you check please and correct my mistakes if I have them.

Comment: Thank you for the $\LaTeX$.  To get functions in the proper font, you put a backslash before them, so \sin and \cos .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your conclusion is correct. Since gravitational force is conservative in nature, work done by it is simply $-mgc.$